# Why the TabBarControl's NavBar appears cut when in page sheet size?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

When I show a `UITabBarController` as Modal, with a `PageSheet` size, the `NavBar` appear cut at the middle.. horizontally.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create a new Project (`iPad`);
2. Put a `UITabBarController` and two other `ViewControllers` in the `Storyboard`;
3. Set the `UITabBarController's` size to `Page Sheet`;
4. Connect the `UITabBarController` with the two `ViewControllers`;
5. Add a button in the main `ViewController`, then add an action to open the `UITabBarController` modally;
6. Start the App in ladscape mode and touch the button to open the `UITabBarController`;
7. Rotate the device and touch the items in the `UITabBarController`.

I already submitted a bug to Apple about this issue.

The test project is here:
[project example](http://www.siteecia.net/temp/ios/test.zip)

And a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

*I also made a video: [youtube video](http://youtu.be/IQweu5QbLoc)

Comment: Did you try activate the autolayout?

Comment: Same problem, Fabio... thanks.